# Erro na String de Conexão no visual studio 2015

Tags: c#

Quando coloco a string de conexão, aparece o seguinte erro:

```
Con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;OutrosParametros");
```

> **Represents text as a series of Unicode characters**

Quando coloco duas barras (**`\\`**) o erro some.

Eu posso usar \\?

Comment: Sim pode usar, acabei de testar aqui e funcionou, no MS Visual Studio 2017. Obrigado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A mensagem

> Represents text as a series of Unicode characters

não é um erro, é a descrição de `string`.

O código realmente tem um erro que é usar a **`\`** como literal, este carácter precisa ser escapado.

Existem duas opções pra isso:

1. Usar **`\`** para escapar esse carácter apenas.

   Ex.: `"Teste\\Teste`" equivale a **`Teste\Teste`**.

   ```
   new SqlConnection("Data Source=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;OutrosParametros");
   ```
2. Usar **`@`** no início da `string`. Isso vai fazer com o que o texto seja representado daquela forma mesmo. Em outras palavras a `string` vira uma *string* literal (ou *verbatim string*).

   Ex.: `@"Teste\nTeste"` equivale a **`Teste\nTeste`**.

   ```
   new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;OutrosParametros");
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Coloca @ antes do seu aspas ("")